# MacBook Pro + Acer H236HL + electric standing desk

Tags: display, macbook-pro, led

I have two external Acer H236HL displays connected to an mid 2015 MacBook Pro Retina all perched on a standing desk. The standing desk is a new addition.

What I am finding is that when I raise or lower the desk, the displays cutout momentarily - something like 1 - 5 seconds.

I thought at first that it might be some kind of power surge, but I put the standing desk on its own circuit.

I am not sure if the root cause of the issue is the displays or the MacBook Pro or both.

Any idea what would cause this?

Here's some video of it: https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipPGtCPR7Iy3_SK2WI1q_-znnA7wopnDopxru8zbwufHopj494qwnhlx9jK-UK740A?key=VDU2ZGs1RTNOdlZmNkExTnJRRmVpX3RGZzBwMmxB

Comment: It still looks like a power issue.  The lights in your room seemed to flicker too.  Are you sure the desk is on its own circuit and not just another outlet on the same circuit?

Comment: The change in lighting was due to the phone camera changing its focus - the lights did not change in actuality. I confirmed that the desk is on another circuit. I also tried plugging my vacuum cleaner into the same power strip as the monitors and they did *not* cut out when the vacuum cleaner was on (which has a much higher draw, amperage wise, than the standing desk)

Comment: Try various things to diagnose.  Try **gently** shaking the monitor.  Try **gently** wiggling each end of the video and power cables.  It seems like a loose connection.  Put the monitors on the floor and then raise the desk.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why your standing desk caused your monitors to blank?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I am going to try some other monitors to see if that makes a difference.